# C# threading with a "Please Wait" form

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

I have a form called "Wait" that is shown and updated throughout my program. It displays the current task being performed and the stage in the task that is being completed.
I have recently started learning about threads and am attempting to implement them into my program. However, I seem to have hit an issue with regards to my Wait Form. I can pass the form into the thread, and the task in the thread will use `Wait.Show()` at the beginning, update the contents of the Wait for, and use `Wait.Hide()` at the end. (I don't use `Wait.Close()` after each task is completed so I don't have to create a new instance of the Wait form for every task.)

My issue is this. My test run will pass the Wait form into the thread successfully, Update it when required, and hide it when finished. However, when I click my Exit button, I can't nullify(?) the Wait form as I receive the following error.

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Frm_Wait' accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was created on.

The code I have for the test run is as follows;

```
    Excel.Application ObjApp = new Excel.Application();
    Specialised Modules = new Specialised();
    ErrorHandling EH = new ErrorHandling();
    Frm_Wait Wait = new Frm_Wait();

    private void BtnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread RCCThread = new Thread(() => UpdateRCCountsThread(Wait));
            RCCThread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
        }
    }


    public void UpdateRCCountsThread(Frm_Wait Wait)
    {
        try
        {
            string RCCountsSource = ResourceDetails.MainResources(this, EH, "RCCounts");
            Wait.Show();

            bool check = Modules.UpdateRCCounts(this, ObjApp, EH, Wait);
            if (check == true)
            {
                //Record completed task to LogFile.
                Thread MsgTaskComplete = new Thread(() => MsgUpdateThread(this, ObjApp, EH, 1, 10, Path.GetDirectoryName(RCCountsSource), Path.GetFileName(RCCountsSource), "", 0, 0, 0, 0, "RC Counts File updated.", "Y"));
                MsgTaskComplete.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An Error occurred, Please Check LogFile.");
            }
            Wait.Hide();
        }
        catch (Exception URC)
        {
            Thread MsgTaskCatch = new Thread(() => MsgUpdateThread(this, ObjApp, EH, 4, 1, "", "", "", 0, 0, 0, 0, "BtnTest_Click Clicked - Error Occurred. System says: " + URC.Message, "N"));
            MsgTaskCatch.Start();
            MessageBox.Show("An Error Occurred" + Environment.NewLine + URC.Message);
        }
    }
```

The portion of code for my Exit button that throws the error is this;

```
            if (Wait != null)
            {
                Wait.Close();
                Wait = null;  //this is the line that causes the error.
            }
```

Does anybody know where I am going wrong? 
Do I have to create a new instance of the Wait form for every thread, or is it possible to pass it through and then return control/ownership back to the main class?

Thank you

Comment: You cannot access an object from another thread that it was created. You created your form in the UI-Thread and you want to access it from the newly created thread.

Use the [invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) / [beginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx) of your control, to invoke the method in the Dispatcher/UI-Thread.

Comment: As far as i can tell, (Remember, I have only just started using Threads) Invoke would be used for editing the contents of the Wait form. This part was working fine and updating normally. I have however added an If InvokeRequired method to handle the updating of the text on the wait form. My issue is when / how to "Show" and "Hide" the form in between threads. If i add the Show in to the button click before the thread is created, and the Hide after the thread is started, the form will only display for less than a second, yet the thread will continue to run.

Comment: For your first statement from the msdn documentation: invoke: _Execute the specified delegate on the thread that owns 'myFormControl1' control's underlying window handle._ 


Your second statement:


As far as I understand you: This is what threads do. Threads would be useless, if you had to wait on their completion. I assume that's why your window hides after one second. Your `UpdateRCCountsThread()`-Method runs in another thread, that means even if you access the form not inside the second nested Thread, you're gonna get this exception.

Comment: So, with my program, i would be waiting for each task to complete before allowing the user to do anything else anyway. Does this mean that threading is pretty pointless in the scope of my work? I.E. They're only useful if you need to do multiple things at once, or carry on using other program features whilst the threaded task works away in the background?

Comment: If your user has to wait anyway, you should at least use something like BackgroundWorker, as you don't want to block the UI while doing some long operation. Otherwise you do everything in the UI-thread which will lead to a blocking UI. Threads are useful for asynchronous or parallel workflows.

Comment: I haven't got to background workers yet. I'm learning as i go. I have the program completed and fully functioning as intended. Now I just need to clean it up and streamline/lighten the processes. However, background workers did come up a lot when i was looking into threading. so this may well be the next thing on my learning list.